# Jest Testing If statement in component not rendering

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Nav component in react that takes User object as props into the component. Depending if they are logged in I change what the nav looks like. Problem is when I test the component and pass props into it - the component doesn't seem to take into account the props being passed in and renders only false part of the if statement.

This is my render function in my component but only seems to render the `else` part when testing in Jest - but renders correctly when in production:

```
render () {
    const user: User = this.props.user

    if (user.isAuthenticated) {
      return this.userLoggedIn(user)
    } else {
      return this.userLoggedOut()
    }
  }
```

Here is my test I'm running - Im just trying to find an img tag that should be only rendered when the `user.isAuthenticated = true`

```
it('Should display text', () => {

const user = {
    isAuthenticated: true
  }
  const store = createStore(combineReducers({ user: authReducer }))
  const logOut = sinon.spy()

  const props = {
    user,
    logOut
  }

  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Nav {...props} />
    </Provider>
  )

    const imgTag = wrapper.find('img')

    expect(imgTag.length).toEqual(1)
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

You should test the both conditions true condition and false condition. Your test only checks the false condition because you write the test of false condition